# URL in the web-browser after login failure using the PRG pattern

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to JQuery-mobile and have stumbled upon a problem I don't know how to solve.

I have two web pages, `index.html` and `user.html`. The `index.html` has a login form, and a POST submit button to a web-service at `/login`. The web-service examines the users credentials and redirects (302) either back to the original `index.html` page or to the `user.html` depending on the success/failure of the authentication.

If the login fails the redirect header's `Location` contains: `index.html`, and here is my problem: If the login fails the browser displays the url `login` rather than the expected `index.html`.

Under 'ordinary' JQuery this works as expected, i.e. the web-browser displays `index.html`, but using JQuery-mobile, the browser retains the url of the POST, even after loading and displaying the `index.html` page.

I would prefer that the url displayed was the page redirected to, in order to make it less likely that a user will bookmark the `login` page rather than the `index.html page.`

Is there any way to either force the browser, or alter the login procedure, in order to get the browser to display `index.html`?

I just discovered that disabling ajax will show the expected `index.html`, so now it appears to be a choice between ajax loading of pages and having the correct url displayed by the browser.

Comment: Try disabling ajax on form/login submitting `data-ajax="false"` to form tag.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, the URL's displayed in the browser are correct both for index and user; and this way I don't have to disable ajax loading completely. Thank you

Comment: Exactly, not completely, only when submitting forms.